# Change image from custoum cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a custoum cell with an image , and i want to change the image only when cell is selected.

This i was trying :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (!tableView.tag==0) {

        TableViewCell2 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        if (!cell) {
            cell=[[TableViewCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }
   // cell.cam.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam_normal.png"];
    cell.cam.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam_selected.png"];
    }
}
```

but the image is not changing.
This is working for a normal cell.

Another try was this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (cell.selected==TRUE) {
            cell.cam.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"cam_selected.png"];
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to have single or multiple selection? And do you want the user to be able to unselect the cell and change the image back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already get the cell as a parameter but fetch another one when using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier!

Try something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (!tableView.tag==0) 
    {
        TableViewCell2 *changeImageCell = (TableViewCell2*) cell;
        changeImageCell.cam.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam_selected.png"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 things:

## 1. Change the image immediately when the cell is selected.

To do this you must first implement `UITableViewCell` delegate. But since you already have `tableViewWillDisplayCel:forRowAtIndexPath:`, I assume that you already have the delegate implemented.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell2 *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cam.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam_selected"];
}
```

You could change the image back when the user deselect the cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell2 *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cam.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam_unselected"];
}
```

## 2. Persist the selection when the cell is reused.

Again, when the cell is reused, you have to check whether it is selected or not. Then assign the image accordingly.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell2 *cell = [tableView dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    BOOL isRowSelected = [indexPath isEqaul:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    if (isRowSelected) {
        cell.cam.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam_selected"];
    } else {
        cell.cam.hightlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam_unselected"];
    }
}
```

Two things I notice here. First you never use `true` or `TRUE` in *Objective-C*. You use `BOOL` with `YES` and `NO`. Second, you rarely need to use `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:` outside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Why did you do it there?